# Why is President Trump ending the DACA program so controversial?

Tags: united-states, immigration, daca

There is currently a [lot of controversy](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-politics/wp/2017/09/05/trump-administration-announces-end-of-immigration-protection-program-for-dreamers/) about President Trump ending the [DACA program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Action_for_Childhood_Arrivals). However I don't understand why it's so controversial — Donald Trump was specifically elected on an anti-immigration platform and canceling a large scale amnesty program seems reasonable within the framework of his electoral promises.

So why is there so much controversy about ending the program?

Comment: The linked article seems to answer your question quite well.

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11485/why-has-there-been-so-much-opposition-to-daca-and-to-the-dreamers?rq=1 related, if not a dupe.

Comment: Is the controversy more than expected? We're pretty divided to start on this issue, and this president is perhaps less liked by his opponents and even some nominal friends than typical.

Comment: The obvious answer to "Why is it controversial" should be because the polls show that DACA is popular. Is that what you are asking or is your question about what makes DACA popular?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you can call DACA amnesty. _Reprieve_, maybe, but _amnesty_ is hyperbole.

Comment: @JeffLambert it provides legal status for people who were in the country illegally. It's an amnesty no matter how you spin it.

Comment: @JonathanReez Maybe that's your opinion, but if it really was amnesty I don't think any of them would really be all that worried right now, because they got amnesty.

Comment: This isn't a question...this is you stating your stance on the issue.

Comment: But to answer your question...a majority of people--including a majority of Trump voters--are actually *for* the program. So when a president goes against that, there's debate and controversy.

Comment: *Donald Trump was specifically elected on an anti-immigration platform* – The election result wasn’t quite unanimous, though, was it? You give an argument for why Trump’s move isn’t necessarily surprising, but not for why it should be uncontroversial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because politics is about perception.

Immigration opponents try to make the face of immigration the killer of [Kate Steinle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Kathryn_Steinle) or the Somali refugees who committed terrorist attacks at [Ohio State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Ohio_State_University_attack) or the [Minnesota mall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Minnesota_mall_stabbing).

Immigration proponents try to make the face of immigration [widows and orphans](http://thehill.com/homenews/administration/260542-obama-gop-refugee-opponents-scared-of-widows-and-orphans) or young children.

The reason for this is that young children (particularly orphans) are more sympathetic than murderers.  Of course, the real problem is more complex.  The states are not mutually exclusive.  The Ohio State terrorist came to the United States (US) as a child.

[Deferred Action for Childhood Arrivals](https://www.uscis.gov/humanitarian/consideration-deferred-action-childhood-arrivals-daca) (DACA) limits include:

1. If not in removal proceedings, must be at least fifteen.
2. Cannot have been born before June 15, 1981.
3. Must have been in the US since at least June 15, 2007.
4. Must have arrived in the US before age 16.
5. Not have had legal status on June 15, 2012.

Obviously a group composed of people ages fifteen to thirty-six doesn't fit most people's idea of children.  So instead of focusing on the bulk of the people impacted, they concentrate on a smaller group.  Some people may be as young as ten.  It's rarer for ten-year-olds to be targeted for removal, but there are some who can be covered by DACA.

They also keep using the word children as much as possible.  While many of those covered by DACA are simple adults, they came here as children.  Some came as young children.  And a nineteen-year-old who came to the US at the age of two may not be a child now, but as a young adult is still more sympathetic than average.

Now, the DACA program is certainly [not legally authorized](http://thehill.com/blogs/pundits-blog/immigration/348832-daca-has-nothing-to-do-with-heart-everything-to-do-with-rule).  A big part of the program is work permits.  The president does not have an unlimited authority to give out work permits.  The administration is supposed to do so in compliance with existing law.  So the courts would have killed it absent a standing claim or other last minute solution to the lawsuit that avoided the legal merits.  So what Donald Trump did actually delays the end of the program for six months.

Immigration proponents do not want to frame the issue that way.  They would far prefer to criticize Trump.  And that also helps them currently.  They want to build more support for their position.  But within the next six months, they will have to choose between continuing some variant of DACA and the status quo.  To continue something like DACA, they will have to compromise with Trump and develop a long term solution that Trump will sign.

A long term solution that preserves something like DACA might also include:

- Funding for Trump's wall (at the US/Mexico border).
- Increased Immigration Control & Enforcement (ICE) funding.
- Mandatory [E-Verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Verify), requiring employers to verify papers showing citizenship status.
- A shift from immigration based primarily on reunification of extended families to one based on a points system that favors employment.
- A reduction in the number of immigrants per year.

Immigration proponents want to give Trump as few of those as possible while still preserving some variant of DACA.  So it is important to them to control the narrative.  And of course the media likes narratives like the mean president hurting defenseless immigrant children.  It plays well with their audience.  So the media's biases favor criticizing Trump on this.

DACA has always been cancelable at any time.  It left millions of people in legal limbo.  Trump's six month reprieve offers a chance to give it real legal status.  Trump abandoning his principles and compromising with opponents.  What's not controversial about that?

Comment: From an electoral-only POV, IMO it is the Republicans who are under pressure, not the Democrats. The Democrats can just say "We want DACA"; if the Republicans agree they will alienate a part of their electorate, if they don't they will alienate another part of it. The Democrats do not actually need a compromise; DACA or not DACA the Republicans will be to blame. It is kind of a reversal of what happened with Obamacare, only that this time there is a deadline.

Comment: A most excellent answer covering both points of view. Wish I could vote twice

Comment: You seem to spend a lot of time emphasizing that they aren't children. The children angle is about when *they arrived*--not that they *are* presently children. Though there's no doubt both sides use extreme examples...I'm not sure if that helps the answer. Every topic has extreme hyperbole on both sides.

Comment: @blip telling a 30 year old guy to return to his home country sounds a lot less cruel than saying the same to an actual child.

Comment: @JonathanReez this *is* their home country. That's the *entire point*.

Comment: @blip depends entirely on one's view on what makes a *home* country.

Comment: @JonathanReez I think you just answered your own question with that statement. :)

Comment: @blip - for an awful lot of them (though of course not all) it's NOT their "home" country, based on their own actions and words. And ironically, it's more of the younger DACA aged ones who think US flag and US as a country is a Bad Thing, because they went through the same US progressive indoctrination as the US born millenials. Google "reconquista". I wouldn't be surprised if under-30 immigrants are **far** more progressive leaning than over-30 ones, by even a bigger margin than US born of same ages.

Comment: @user4012 your argument is that progressives hate the US flag? Umm...

Comment: @blip Maybe he is thinking of the Confederate flag? I'm still not sure what we were supposed to get from Google searching "Reconquista".

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara These are a few people asking for the devolution to Mexico of the territories taken away by the USA. It is just the usual fringe group of few people making absurd claims that you can find about almost anything (9-11 conspiracy theories, birthers, etc.) and completely irrelevant. But it is useful to dishonest people as strawman against **all** the millions of people of Hispanic ascendency in the USA, because fear-mongering (`indoctrination`, `they think the US is a bad thing`) is a good way to replace logical discurse by an emotional one without being too overtly racist.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara To see an historical example of how it works, [Milo Radulovich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo_Radulovich) was accused of being Communist just because he was of Eastern European ascendency, her sister was a supporter of liberal causes (`indoctrinated`, some would say) and his father was reading newspapers from his homeland... I do not know what others think, but I believe that punishing the sons of an Eastern European immigrant mainly because they are the sons of an Eastern European immigrant is a bad thing...

Comment: @blip as far as I understood your thought process: Let's assume you have a huge house and some child (not yours) is able to hide in it for some time. After what time can the child claim your house his home?

Comment: @SalvadorDali let's not assume silly things in general for the sake of goofy arguments.

Comment: @blip can you describe why is it silly? The one difference I see between my example and yours is that in my example the property belong to only one person and in yours it is a collective property.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I could describe how it's silly but them I'm partaking in the goofy argument. :) But to make you happy: DACA does not allow people to claim citizenship anymore than a trespasser can claim ownership of your house (nitpicky issues of squatter's rights aside...)

Comment: "The president does not have an unlimited authority to give out work permits." This is legally debatable. INA 274A(h)(3) defines someone not authorized to work in the US as someone who is not (A) a US permanent resident or (B) "authorized to be so employed by this Act or by the Attorney General", which means whoever the executive branch (i.e. the Attorney General) specifies (through appropriate rulemaking process) is authorized to work is authorized to work, and thus should be able to get EADs as documentation of such authorization.

Comment: A large fraction of the several dozen categories of EADs are not specifically provided for by provisions in statutes, and only provided for by executive branch regulations. If you argue that the executive branch can only issue EADs for situations that are specifically mentioned in statute, then a large number of categories of EADs would be invalid.

Answer (score 6):

Because DACA is about people who did nothing wrong.

With undocumented immigrants who came to the US as adults, even those on the left are sometimes convinced by the argument that they did something illegal and should face the consequences for that.

DACA on the other hand is about those that came here before their 16th birthday. They had no choice, they grew up in the US, and many know nothing about their country of origin. These are Americans who are unlucky to not have the American citizenship. Because of this, even some on the right can sometimes put themselves in their shoes.

And while Trump was elected on a platform of anti-immigration, only 46% of voters voted for him (and that doesn't take the demographics of non-voters into account yet). Many who voted against him specifically voted against this platform, so it shouldn't be surprising that any action in this regard will be controversial.